# Question regarding the Category 3 PRIIP MRM calculation

Tags: value-at-risk, banking-regulations, bootstrap

My question is regarding the European Commission regulation on standardizing the information in the key information documents for PRIIPs. In the [Annex IV](http://ec.europa.eu/finance/finservices-retail/docs/investment_products/20160630-delegated_regulation-annex_en.pdf) of the regulation, one can find the explanation on the determination of an MRM class for the category 3 products (paras. 16-24)

Now my question is regarding calculation of the return of the underlying contract, as explained in para. 22, and specifically the formula in 22c:

$Return = E[Return_{risk-neutral}] - E[Return_{measured}] - 0.5\sigma^2N - \rho\sigma\sigma_{ccy}N$

Could anybody give more details on this formula? I personally do not think I fully understand the first two terms in the formula.

I also tried to reproduce the category 3 calculation as given in the [Commission presentation](http://ec.europa.eu/finance/events/2016/0711-workshop-priips-framework/docs/160711-risk-section-kid_en.pdf), but I miss the point after summing up the simulated daily returns, i.e. step 9.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is not very clear the legislation. However, from some slides that EIOPA used in a conference I tried to build back their computation and what I found is that:

1) you simulate 10k with lenght T, so you have a matrix 10k x T

2) you sum over the Ts so you get a vector 10k x 1

3) you have to go in the risk neutral world so from every element from 1 to 10k you remove the historical mean, add the risk free and remove FX risk/variance

Comment: Thank you. I also tried to reproduce the calculation (I guess from the same presentation[1]), however it is not possible to get the exact same result. Their final return is equal to 1.057013249, which is 0.055447241 as a lognormal value. However, 
Sum of Returns = 0.029342;
-10*Mean = 0.022725205;
-10*Variance/2 = -0.000667217;
With a risk free rate of 1.2% p.a., i don't see how to end up with 0.055447241. How did you solve that?

[1] https://ec.europa.eu/info/system/files/risk-section-kid-11072016_en.pdf